# Custom schema for XML comments in Visual Studio for C#

Tags: visual-studio, xml-comments

When I type "///" in the editor, Visual Studio creates an empty comment body with the < summary > and other tags. I can then type the "<" and VS suggests a list of [recommended tags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax(v=vs.80).aspx).

How can I make the IntelliSense to suggest my custom tags here?

Ideally, I would like to have my own XML documentation template expanded when I type "///"

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this.
It is primarily targeted at VS2005 en 2008, but it's probably still valid for 2010 with minor differences.

[Documenting Your Code With XML Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd722812.aspx#id0400027)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, Gerald! I've seen this article. The proposed solution works for VB but, unfortunately, not for C#.

Comment: Hm, I assumed it would be available in C# as well. After a little further investigation it seems it isn't! You can vote here to get it in: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2709987-xml-comments-schema-customization-in-c-

Comment: I did... But I hope there are probably other ways to make it work before Microsoft implements this feature.

Comment: Well, if it is hard-coded into VS2010 right now, I don't think there is.