# C#: Change default tripple slash (///) tags

Tags: c#, xml, comments

Is it possible to change the editor's behavior of what tags are displayed by default when using typing ///?

For example, I would like the editor to add a tag for the `<author>` and remove the tag of the `<return type>`.

So instead of:

```
/// <summary>
/// Some summary
/// </summary>
/// <param name="name">My param description </param>
```

I would like something like:

```
 /// <summary> Some summary </summary>
```

It has been suggested that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929697/custom-schema-for-xml-comments-in-visual-studio-for-c-sharp) is a duplicate, but the answer given there are for VB.  From the comments (in 2013) it seems like it is not availalbe in 2013.  Does anyone know if that is still the case with VS 2015?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom schema for XML comments in Visual Studio for C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929697/custom-schema-for-xml-comments-in-visual-studio-for-c-sharp)

Comment: The recommended list of tags [doesn't include `author`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574580/how-to-document-the-author-in-c-sharp-xml). Are you planning on only ever letting one person edit each of these methods? Aren't you using version control?

Comment: @Matthew Strawbridge: Yes, I do agree that author will represent version control.  Maybe not the best example.  I'll change the question a bit.

Comment: You could try [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) -- it probably gives you the control you're looking for